# Joining two data frames and result data frames contain non duplicate items in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created two data frames by executing below command. I want to
join the two data frames and result data frames contain non duplicate items in PySpark.

```py
df1 = sc.parallelize([
     ("a",1,1),
     ("b",2,2),
     ("d",4,2),
     ("e",4,1),
     ("c",3,4)]).toDF(['SID','SSection','SRank'])
df1.show()
```

```
+---+--------+-----+
|SID|SSection|SRank|
+---+--------+-----+
|  a|       1|    1|
|  b|       2|    2|
|  d|       4|    2|
|  e|       4|    1|
|  c|       3|    4|
+---+--------+-----+
```

df2 is

```py
df2=sc.parallelize([
    ("a",2,1),
    ("b",2,3),
    ("f",4,2),
    ("e",4,1),
    ("c",3,4)]).toDF(['SID','SSection','SRank'])
```

```
+---+--------+-----+
|SID|SSection|SRank|
+---+--------+-----+
|  a|       2|    1|
|  b|       2|    3|
|  f|       4|    2|
|  e|       4|    1|
|  c|       3|    4|ggVG
+---+--------+-----+
```

I want to join above two tables like below.

```
+---+--------+----------+----------+
|SID|SSection|test1SRank|test2SRank|
+---+--------+----------+----------+
|  f|       4|         0|         2|
|  e|       4|         1|         1|
|  d|       4|         2|         0|
|  c|       3|         4|         4|
|  b|       2|         2|         3|
|  a|       1|         1|         0|
|  a|       2|         0|         1|
+---+--------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like something that can be achieved with a single join. Here's a solution involving multiple joins:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

d1 = df1.unionAll(df2).select("SID" , "SSection" ).distinct()

t1 = d1.join(df1 , ["SID", "SSection"] , "leftOuter").select(d1.SID , d1.SSection , col("SRank").alias("test1Srank"))

t2 = d1.join(df2 , ["SID", "SSection"] , "leftOuter").select(d1.SID , d1.SSection , col("SRank").alias("test2Srank"))

t1.join(t2, ["SID", "SSection"]).na.fill(0).show()

+---+--------+----------+----------+
|SID|SSection|test1Srank|test2Srank|
+---+--------+----------+----------+
|  b|       2|         2|         3|
|  c|       3|         4|         4|
|  d|       4|         2|         0|
|  e|       4|         1|         1|
|  f|       4|         0|         2|
|  a|       1|         1|         0|
|  a|       2|         0|         1|
+---+--------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply *rename* the `SRank` column names and use *outer join* and use `na.fill` function

```
df1.withColumnRenamed("SRank", "test1SRank").join(df2.withColumnRenamed("SRank", "test2SRank"), ["SID", "SSection"], "outer").na.fill(0)
```